# javaFX TreeView with different Data Objects

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a small problem with my TreeView..
There are always six "root" elements - always. So i'm using `TreeItrem<String>`.
At the next step the application walks through my file systems and creates same `FileModels` with some specific datas like the size of the file etc.

Now i want to list these models in my `TreeView`. That works fine.
But how can i save the data from the model to the specific `TreeItem`?
I can't mix the `TreeView<String>` with `TreeItem<FileModel>` - or it is possible??
How you understand what i'm mean. I want to use the data at my event listeners...

```
@FXML
private TreeView<String> treeView;

// ....

TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<>("Root");

TreeItem<String> test = new TreeItem<>("Test");
TreeItem<String> test2 = new TreeItem<>("Test2");
TreeItem<String> test3 = new TreeItem<>("Test3");
TreeItem<String> test4 = new TreeItem<>("Test4");
TreeItem<String> test5 = new TreeItem<>("Test5");
TreeItem<String> test6 = new TreeItem<>("Test6");

rootItem.getChildren().addAll(
    test, test2 //....
);

myObjectCache.getAllObjects().foreach((k, v) -> {
    switch(v.getType) {
        case TEST:
            test.getChildren.add(new TreeItem<>(v.getTitle));
            break;
        case TEST2:
            test2.getChildren.add(new TreeItem<>(v.getTitle));
            break;
        case TEST3:
            test3.getChildren.add(new TreeItem<>(v.getTitle));
            break;
            // ....
    }
});

//....
```

Comment: Can it be done? Yes. Should it be done? Most likely No. Could you explain why a `TreeItem<String>` is not sufficient?

Comment: I don't know how to get the internal id of the element of a `TreeItem<String>. After a click on a item i want to display more informations on the right sight of the application and i don't know where i can save the informations to get the element...